# Datagridview Control modifies another

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I'm trying to add values to my second `combobox` based on the choice of my first `combobox` in my `datagridview` (which contains `textbox` columns as well).

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Try
        'Sub Recurrence combobox is selected
        If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
            'Verify what is chosen in the Recurrence textbox
            Dim rowIndex = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
            Dim FirstComboboxValue = DataGridView1(3, rowIndex).Value

            If Not IsNothing(FirstComboboxValue) Then
                Dim cmb As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
                RemoveHandler cmb.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
                AddHandler cmb.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

My handlers fire the trigger towards the ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
        Dim comboBox As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
        Dim cbCell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(4), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        Dim rowIndex = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        Dim FirstComboboxValue = DataGridView1(3, rowIndex).Value

        'Clear items so they don't keep adding on each other
        cbCell.Items.Clear()

        Select Case FirstComboboxValue
            Case "Choice1"
                cbCell.Items.Add("Item1")
                cbCell.Items.Add("Item2")
            Case "Choice2"
                cbCell.Items.Add("Item3")
                cbCell.Items.Add("Item4")
            Case "Choice3"
                cbCell.Items.Add("Item5")
            Case "Choice4"
                cbCell.Items.Add("Item6")
                cbCell.Items.Add("Item7")
        End Select

        'Remove event handler to prevent memory leak
        RemoveHandler comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged
    End If
End Sub
```

For some reason, when I use a break-point and step through the program, the items get added in the second `combobox` only on the 2nd time that I try ty open the "item" `combobox`.

If I try to run the program without debugging, nothing is displayed. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SelectedIndexChanged in your ComboBox may be you encounter a problem with events being fired even if you did not click the ComboBox.

This happens when you open and close your Windows Form.

A better one for this by using the **SelectionChangeCommitted** event.

SelectionChangeCommitted event occurs when the selected item has changed and that change is displayed in the ComboBox.

By using SelectionChangeCommitted event you do not need to declare RemoveHandler and AddHandler statement.

---

Another possibility:

Try it with **Handles cmb.SelectedIndexChanged**

There are several ways to declare events in VB.NET. The usual one is using the handles keyword.

```
Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object,
            ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cmb.SelectedIndexChanged
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! Unfortunately that would error out due to the method being declared outside my EditingControlShowing event. It wouldn't know what to do with "cmb"

Comment: I understand that this would work for a normal combobox control. The problem is we're dealing with a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and they need the handlers in order to work

Comment: Hve you tried it with the : SelectionChangeCommitted Event with addHandler and removeHandler ?

Comment: Yep, same result as SelectedIndexChanged, unfortunately. Meanwhile, I'll just develop another form which adds the information in the datagridview. It's a workaround but I'll try to work on this during the weekend on my own time as well.